# Which rules advance the chapter end marker in Mice and Mystics?

Tags: mice-and-mystics

There are some rules, such as many of the achievements, that advance the chapter end marker in Mice and Mystics. Which other rules, cards or events do this?

Our experiences so far are that the hourglass advances pretty quickly. We already lost two times in the first level because of this. So I am interested if we missed some rules that play in our favour, and which for example advance the end marker, to give us more time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only things that move it are achievements and specific story line events that will be listed in the story book.  I believe Chapter 1 has one or two of those.

Some tips for keeping the pages from advancing too quickly:

- Try to get the first attack.  Most rooms start with the monsters a ways away from you.  If you act first, hold back out of their range.  They will blindly charge forward and you will be able to get in the first attack next round.
- Don't be too stingy with your cheese.  Using special abilities kills monsters faster, reducing the number of dice you roll that could come up cheese.
- Don't spend a lot of time searching after you've killed the last enemy.  Try to have the last mouse on the track be in position to explore, and only let the people in between search.  Some times you can delay killing the last enemy to give yourself a bit more time, but this can also backfire.
- Don't spend a lot of actions healing during battle.  Kill the enemies first, then heal before leaving the room.
- If someone is getting close to an achievement like Roach Master, you can leave the final kills for them so that they can advance the end marker for you.